# loading value from element using xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm kinda new to xpath. So I don't know how to do this. I have this file

```
<map>    
    <object name="object (1)">
        <position>564.014893 -7424.033691 35.448875</position>
        <rotation>0.000000 0.000000 0.000000</rotation>
        <model>3494</model>
    </object>
</map>
```

As you can see in position;

564.014893 -7424.033691 35.448875

564.014893 is X

-7424.033691 is Y

35.448875 is Z

How do I load X(or Y/Z)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have xpath 2 support, you can use tokenize to split the string on spaces. The X, Y and Z values would respectively be:

```
tokenize(map/object/position, ' ')[1]
tokenize(map/object/position, ' ')[2]
tokenize(map/object/position, ' ')[3]
```

If you only have xpath 1 support, you could use the substring-before and substring-after methods. The X, Y, and Z values would respectively be:

```
substring-before(map/object/position, " ")
substring-before(substring-after(map/object/position, " "), " ")
substring-after(substring-after(map/object/position, " "), " ")
```

Comment: It says; Unrecognized function
Maybe I could load them with any of this?
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Both solutions give unrecognized function? What are you using to evaluate the xpaths - ie what functions are supported? I do not think the link you provided will help, unless you want to just get the entire text node and then parse the text using something other than xpath.